# How can I scroll multiple div on one fixed div?

Tags: html, css

This person has a portfolio: https://eliasakentour.com/about

If you look at it you will notice that his first page gets scrolled on top by the second one.. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="
background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
height: 100vh;
overflow-y: scroll;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;

">
  <div  style="height: 100vh;background-color: transparent">


  </div>
  <div  style="height: 100vh;background-color: green"></div>
  <div  style="height: 100vh;background-color: transparent"></div>
</div>
```